# Plugin: BuddyPress Activity Plus - How can I call the full size image?

Tags: buddypress

I’m using the BuddyPress Activity Plus plugin and wanted to know if there was a way to call the full size image that was uploaded when viewing the single page of the activity?

I’ve looked at placing a line of code in “activity/entry.php” of the child theme but can’t find anything that will call its full size image, only the thumbnail shows with the link to the full size image to open in a lightbox.

This isn’t what I’m looking for, the full size image needs to be in place of the thumbnail when viewing the single activity page.

Any idea anyone? Sorry if this is the right place for this, just having trouble getting an answer

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do a similar thing, not too much luck yet. Also - have you noticed that if you upload multiple images, they stack, rather then laying out side by side?

**EDIT:**

Found out how to make the images in the stream bigger:

You can set your preferred thumbnail size separately from your default thumbnail size settings, if you wish to do so. You can do that by adding this line to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('BPFB_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_SIZE', '200x200');
```

Where "200x200" are width and height (in that order), in pixels.

Finally, be sure to verify your default sizes for embedded media. It's in Settings -> Media -> Embeds -> Maximum embed size